# set MTU for device with multiple interfaces

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, ioctl, mtu

I am using

> ioctl(s, SIOCSIFMTU, (caddr_t)&ifr)

to change the MTU for an interface.

code is similar to this

```
struct ifreq ifr; 
ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;
//iap->ifa_name is bond1:xx
strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, iap->ifa_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name));
ifr.ifr_mtu = 1492; 
ioctl(s, SIOCSIFMTU, (caddr_t)&ifr)
```

My problem is that the device has multiple interfaces and that the MTU is set to 1492
for all of these. I want to do it specifically for only one interface, leaving all the others not impacted. How can I do it?

bond1:43  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0E:0C:E4:C5:45
          inet addr:10.7.181.59  Bcast:10.7.181.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:**1492**  Metric:1

bond1:48  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0E:0C:E4:C5:45
          inet addr:10.7.181.60  Bcast:10.7.181.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:**1492**  Metric:1

bond1:49  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0E:0C:E4:C5:45
          inet addr:10.7.181.61  Bcast:10.7.181.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:**1492**  Metric:1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to update MTU for the specific interface you shallset `ifr_name` field of the `struct ifreq` to the name of the interface

**EDIT:**  You problem is in the name of the interface. The number after the column in the interface name is just an alias. Actually, you don't have several different interfaces it's the same interface. That is why you setting is applied onto all interfaces with name *"bond:xx"*

Comment: I am doing that. Check the strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, iap->ifa_name, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name)); but it still does not work

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. The problem in the interface name. See the updated answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't fix it, since it's the same interface with the same MAC address and other properties. The only thing is to use different physical interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

This may work . Get the Alias interface first and the set the MTU .

```
ioctl(s, SIOCGIFALIAS, (caddr_t)&ifr)
```